# consolidate over +1500 wav files and slice them again (in PHP)

Tags: php, wav, consolidation

Because I'd like to save a lot of work, I've tried to make a function to consolidate wav files per folder.
The folder(s) contain about 100 till 500 wav files.
All wav files are stereo, 44.100 Hz and 24bits.

There are over 1500 lose wav files, which can't be edited by batch processing, because the program I'm using (for other specific reasons) does not have a batch processing option. 
Therefor I trie to:
-> Consolidate wav files + 0.5s of silence and make a cue list
-> edit large files (done in music edit software)
-> split large files back to it's original files (exact) by cue list (without the silence)

It seems to me, the best way is to remove the file header (save it in a cue) and just join the bytes?

The only language I know so far is PHP, so all that I tried to achieve is in PHP.
I figured out I lack the skills and knowledge to do this and I hope someone can help here.

The basic things I've tried to accomplish are:
-Make an array of all wav files
-Add 0.5s of silence after each file(in the array)
-Create final array to convert file back to original
-Remove the file header
-Create new wave file.

Some basic function:

```
function wav_scan_dir($directory){  
   $filenames = array();
   $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
   foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {

     if ($fileinfo->isFile() && $fileinfo->getExtension() === "wav") {
       $filenames[$fileinfo->getFilename()] = filesize($directory.$fileinfo->getFilename());
     }
}

    return $filenames;  
}

$directory = dirname(__FILE__)."/WAVES/";
$files = wav_scan_dir($directory);
```

***Because of comment extra info:**

folder contains: 01original.wav, 02original.wav, 03original.wav.

edit to

onebigfile.wav = 01original.wav +0.5silence, 02original.wav, +0.5silence, 03original.wav.

After edit return to (same exact size/length as original wav files):

01original.wav, 02original.wav, 03original.wav.*

Comment: Do all your wave files have the same format and sample rate? If not, there's no way to combine them losslessly.

Comment: They all have a sample rate of: 44.100 Hz and are 24bits.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on your ultimate goal.  By consolidate wav files do you mean append one or more WAVs to the end of another and then add silence?

Comment: I tried to give a better explanation in the op.

Comment: Ok in that case I was going to suggest this [WavFile class](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage/blob/master/WavFile.php) made by myself and one other person.  It supports appending wav files as well as mixing them and has a function for adding silence.  It doesn't support extra fields like COMMENT data at the moment so if you have any of that information in the files it will lose it.  Hope that can help.  If it looks interesting let me know and I can just post a quick example of code specific to your case.

Comment: Wow that looks like a nice Class in any case! Audio editing in PHP. I can't see in a quick scan if it covers this specific case. So if you'd like to give an example that would be nice.